# How do I format long lines in Twig templates, according to coding standards?

Tags: php, html, symfony, coding-style, twig

I have the following code in my templates, in which I'm generating routes with parameters:

```
<a class="btn btn-block btn-abcd" href="{{ path(
    'auth.login',
    {
        'type': constant('User::TYPE_CANDIDATE'),
        'provider': constant('UserProvider::PROVIDER_XING')
    }
) }}">...</a>
```

I've split it up into lines the way I'd do it with PHP code. I'm just not sure if this is the recommended practice or not. The [coding standards page on the Twig site](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/coding_standards.html) doesn't address this specific issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A commonly used technique for readability, is that whenever you feel you need to shorten lines, you do it at an open parenthesis/bracket/brace. Not necessarily on all of them, but one that makes sense.

Here is my recommendation:

```
<a class="btn btn-block btn-abcd"
    href="{{ path(
        'auth.login', {
            'type': constant('User::TYPE_CANDIDATE'),
            'provider': constant('UserProvider::PROVIDER_XING')
        }
    ) }}">
    Link text
</a>
```

One problem with single-line reformatting, is that a lot of mess detectors and linters will scoff at lines longer than 50 characters.

Comment: I like this. It even demonstrates how to format tag attributes and content.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest splitting instead according to common PHP rules as you originally suggested - just treat Twig tags like `{{` and `{%` the same as `<?php` tags.

The standards I follow for my projects are available here: https://github.com/cybtachyon/twig-standards.

I reformatted [Alec](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2560666/alec)'s answer to follow more of the above Twig standards.

```
<a class="btn btn-block btn-abcd" href="{{
  path(
    'auth.login',
    {
      'type': constant('User::TYPE_CANDIDATE'),
      'provider': constant('UserProvider::PROVIDER_XING'),
    }
  )
  }}">
    Link text
</a>
```